# ¿Cómo extraer una fila de data de un df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Como puedo extraer la fila N de mi data frame

> ```
> >>>BD
>
>
>          AAPL         MSFT         XOM        JNJ         JPM          AMZN         GE         FB       T  
> 0      0.143335     0.003217    0.238816    0.181586    0.085305     0.029136   0.040685   0.073971  0.203950
> 1      0.246245     0.059063    0.031106    0.017317    0.045353     0.214421   0.127492   0.073092  0.185911
> 2      0.038312     0.006075    0.072793    0.044644    0.016160     0.003624   0.010822   0.520474  0.287095
> 3      0.162723     0.087614    0.049509    0.229241    0.108593     0.012520   0.246437   0.040767  0.062598
> ```

y que me aparezca de la siguiente manera

> ```
>  >>>array([0.143335, 0.003217, 0.238816, 0.181586 , 0.085305,     0.029136, 0.040685, 0.073971, 0.203950])
> ```

según la fila que escoja, sin ningún titulo de las columnas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma correcta es usar [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) para indexar por índice entero y el método [`to_array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) (desde Pandas  0.24.0) para obtener el array NumPy a partir de la Serie (fila):

Por ejemplo, para la primera fila:

```
arr = df.iloc[0].to_array()
```

Ten en cuenta que esto retorna una vista siempre, por lo que modificar el array conlleva modificar el DataFrame.

```
>>> arr = df.iloc[0].to_numpy()
>>> arr[0] = 13
>>> df

        AAPL      MSFT       XOM       JNJ       JPM      AMZN        GE        FB         T
0  13.000000  0.003217  0.238816  0.181586  0.085305  0.029136  0.040685  0.073971  0.203950
1   0.246245  0.059063  0.031106  0.017317  0.045353  0.214421  0.127492  0.073092  0.185911
2   0.038312  0.006075  0.072793  0.044644  0.016160  0.003624  0.010822  0.520474  0.287095
3   0.162723  0.087614  0.049509  0.229241  0.108593  0.012520  0.246437  0.040767  0.062598
```

Si no quieres esto, debes obtener una copia, lo cual consigues mediante el argumento `copy`:

```
arr = df.iloc[0].to_numpy(copy=True)
arr[0] = 13
>>> df

       AAPL      MSFT       XOM       JNJ       JPM      AMZN        GE        FB         T
0  0.143335  0.003217  0.238816  0.181586  0.085305  0.029136  0.040685  0.073971  0.203950
1  0.246245  0.059063  0.031106  0.017317  0.045353  0.214421  0.127492  0.073092  0.185911
2  0.038312  0.006075  0.072793  0.044644  0.016160  0.003624  0.010822  0.520474  0.287095
3  0.162723  0.087614  0.049509  0.229241  0.108593  0.012520  0.246437  0.040767  0.062598

>>> arr
array([1.30000e+01, 3.21700e-03, 2.38816e-01, 1.81586e-01, 8.53050e-02,
       2.91360e-02, 4.06850e-02, 7.39710e-02, 2.03950e-01])
```

Solo si usas una versión anterior a 0.24, debes usar el atributo [values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values):

```
arr = df.iloc[0].values.copy()
```

---

Ten en cuenta que no es lo mismo seleccionar la primera fila (`iloc[0]`) que seleccionar la fila con etiqueta 0 en el índice (`loc`) en el DataFrame:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd



data = StringIO("""\
           AAPL         MSFT         XOM        JNJ         JPM          AMZN         GE         FB        T  
3      0.143335     0.003217    0.238816    0.181586    0.085305     0.029136   0.040685   0.073971  0.203950
7      0.246245     0.059063    0.031106    0.017317    0.045353     0.214421   0.127492   0.073092  0.185911
0      0.038312     0.006075    0.072793    0.044644    0.016160     0.003624   0.010822   0.520474  0.287095
4      0.162723     0.087614    0.049509    0.229241    0.108593     0.012520   0.246437   0.040767  0.062598
""")


df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+")
```

> ```
> >>> df.iloc[0]
> AAPL    0.143335
> MSFT    0.003217
> XOM     0.238816
> JNJ     0.181586
> JPM     0.085305
> AMZN    0.029136
> GE      0.040685
> FB      0.073971
> T       0.203950
> Name: 0, dtype: float64
>
>
> >>> df.loc[0]
> AAPL    0.038312
> MSFT    0.006075
> XOM     0.072793
> JNJ     0.044644
> JPM     0.016160
> AMZN    0.003624
> GE      0.010822
> FB      0.520474
> T       0.287095
> Name: 0, dtype: float64
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla

Comment: En verdad me ha servido de mucho tu ayuda